# Read value/content of a file from Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

Is it possible to read the value a file without using the download function?

Something instead of:

```
storageRef.child('text.txt').getDownloadURL().then(function() {
  ...
});
```

Something like:

```
storageRef.child('text.txt').getValue().then(function(value) {
  alert(value)
});
```

Comment: What is the difference between "read" and "download" in your mind? Just do an XMLHttpRequest get on the download URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no available function to directly read a file in Firebase Storage in JavaScript without downloading it first.

You can file a Feature Request [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/), if you think this would be really useful.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same trouble with getting content of the file in Firebase Storage, but finally, I found there is no way to read the file content directly.
However, I did it like this.

```
  fileRef.getDownloadURL()
    .then(url => {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.responseType = 'json'; 
      xhr.onload = function(event) {
        var json= xhr.response;
        console.log(json);      // now you read the file content
      };
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.send();
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // process exceptions
    })
```

**What is important was configuring the CORS settings.** You can find the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files?authuser=0#cors_configuration).

Skipping this instruction made me consume much time :/ 
I hope others avoid the same mistakes. Thanks.