# Writing to Files in Firebase Storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a html file inside my Firebase storage(say hello.html).I have an html content
`<div>Hello world</div>`
I need to write this content to the above hello.html in the storage.How to do this using Firebase Cloud Functions??

Comment: There are some promising leads in here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-functions%5D+write+file+to+storage

Answer (score 1):

For you to be able to perform that, it will depend on the way that your file is uploaded on the Firebase and how you would like to edit them.

Considering that, I would recommend you to take a look at the below links, to verify the options that are available for you to edit.

- [Using Firebase Cloud Functions to Update Hosted File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912527/using-firebase-cloud-functions-to-update-hosted-file)
- [Tutorial: How to upload files using Firebase](https://medium.com/@puoygae/tutorial-how-to-upload-files-using-firebase-fbe598538c52)
- [Read value/content of a file from Firebase Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992202/read-value-content-of-a-file-from-firebase-storage)

Let me know if the information helped you!